# Fit data to a bivariate function

Tags: model-selection, model, curve-fitting, polynomial, bivariate

I want to fit my (x,y,z) data points to a function.
You can see the data on Fig.1.

[image: Fig. 1. My data]

The data is symmetric along the main diagonal.
To understand my data I have studied (y,z) curves at different values of x. I have made the following conclusions:

**1.** When **x = 0** the (y,z) curve is a **line**
$$z = k * y^1 + l$$

[image]

**2.** When **x = max(x)/2** (in the middle) the (y,z) curve is **polynomial of degree 1.5** $$z = k * y^{1.5} + l$$

[image]

**3.** When **x = max(x)** the (y,z) curve is **polynomial of degree 2**
$$z = k * y^2 + l$$

[image]

Therefore, each "cut" of my data can be explained *using a polynomial function where **the degree ranges from 1 to 2***.

Still I have a problem fitting it all together using a bivariate function.

**What I need is**: $$z = func(x,y)$$

Could you suggest anything?

Comment: To match the three conditional relationships in your question, you'd look for something like $E(z)=a_x+b_x y^{c+dx}$, where $a_x$ and $b_x$ vary with $x$. Given that xmin=0, it may be that $c=0$. However, I don't think it's possible to make this functional form match the symmetry condition.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to figure it out myself.

The equation is:
$$z = a_1\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

On the plot below you can see how the observed data (black filled points) fit to the model (red unfilled points).

[image]

Looking at slices of my data (see my question above) I`ve suggested that the "core" of my function should be a product of x and y that has first degree when x=0 or y=0 and second degree when both x and y are non-negative. This is because at x=0 the (y,z) curve is a line and then with x>0 each next slice of (y,z) becomes parabolic with a higher degree (and the same for y and (x,z)).
I`ve tried several options and finally discovered that $$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ does the trick.

Now I have two questions:

1. I`ve actually guessed the correct solution. But is there a way to derive it systematically? Some kind of integration over several "slice-functions"?
2. Does this equation have a name?

Comment: Your question specifies a y-z relationship for 3 x-values (in each case, $z$ linear in $y^p$, with $p$ linear in $x$) but your solution doesn't match the conditions in your question (e.g. where you say the relationship is linear in $y^{1.5}$ or $y^2$, your solution isn't). That is, you requested a particular, specific thing (the question doesn't appear to admit solutions that are not of the proposed form), yet your solution doesn't do what you asked for. While it seems this is a pretty good fit to the data, how is this an answer to the question that you actually asked?

Comment: By the way, answers are not a place to ask followup questions. Questions go in questions spaces, and answer spaces should contain answers.